# How to declare a function in a PLSQL block and call same in a select query?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a code like this-:

```
DECLARE

  --BEGIN
  V_DATE DATE;

  FUNCTION GETDATE(NUM_DAYS NUMBER) RETURN DATE IS
      PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION; 
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO LEAVE.GES_LEV_REQ_PURG_ERR VALUES (NUM_DAYS, NUM_DAYS, SYSDATE);
        COMMIT;
    RETURN(SYSDATE);
  END GETDATE;

BEGIN

  --V_DATE := GETDATE(1);
  SELECT GETDATE(1) INTO V_DATE FROM DUAL;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_DATE);

END;
/
```

But this is throwing below error-

```
ORA-06550: line 17, column 10:
PLS-00231: function 'GETDATE' may not be used in SQL
ORA-06550: line 17, column 10:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 17, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

While if I am calling that function without select query, it works fine.
Please help.

Comment: DML(insert in your case) is forbidden in select queries.

Comment: `V_DATE := GETDATE(1);` it is ok, isn't it?

Comment: Yes this is fine.
But I have to use it in a select query like this.

SELECT GETDATE(1) INTO V_DATE FROM DUAL;
Work arorund.

Comment: With PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS we can use I guess.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, surely you can run DML in a function, but not in queries.

Comment: It is a bad idea to do DML inside a function. Especially when your requirement is to call it in SQL.You could write a procedure and do your DML first and then send SYSDATE as OUT parameter. But just don't understand why are you complicating it so much. All I see is that you have an `INSERT` statement and rest everything seems useless.

Comment: If you want to use custom function in SQL you must declared it on database level (create this function or add it into package spec)

Comment: This is a bogus example.  Please explain why you want to declare your function in an anonymous block instead of building it with CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION .  Also, which version of Oracle database are you using?

Comment: Actually this is a part of package and that package has some error, and problem is , I cannot change in package directly due to some access issue. So trying to convert it into declare begin block. so that I can run it for time being. But this is not working.
P.S- This is simplified block I made for understanding

Comment: *Why* do you have to run it from a SQL select query rather than via a PL/SQL assignment, as Florin suggested earlier? You're calling it from inside your block either way, so why do you think you need the `select` version? And if you're running this block to avoid a package problem, why are you bothering with the complexity, why not just do a straight insert?

Comment: As I said this a simplified version I made for understanding, actual package is very complex. Please don't get into why this why that? I wanted to know whether this can be handled in a block, that's it. :/

Answer (score 3):

Nested sub programs can be used in the scope of the procedure where it has been created. Nested subprograms cannot be used in SQL since it is not directly available as DB object. Please be aware that there are two engines executing your PL/SQL block(SQL Engine & PL/SQL Engine). While executing your query with nested function, SQL engine tries to match the function name with the DB object. But in your case it is a subprogram inside a procedure. Hope I am understandable.

And as you said, you could perform DML inside a function and it could be used in SQL provided it is declared as PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION

Answer (score 1):

> There are Basically two thing which need to ask before we proceed for
>   any answer. 1) What is the exact use for this kind of call or block.
>   2) Why you are not going for FUCNTION creation first and then call it.
>
> NOTE : [ Anyhow you cannot call a FUNCTION in SELECT statement if it
>   has DML operations involved in it. ]
>
> I will try to illustrate the ay it should work. Let me know if it
>   helps

```
--Create Function


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GETDATE(
    NUM_DAYS NUMBER)
  RETURN DATE
IS
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO LEAVE.GES_LEV_REQ_PURG_ERR VALUES
    (NUM_DAYS, NUM_DAYS, SYSDATE
    );
  COMMIT;
  RETURN(SYSDATE);
END GETDATE;

-- Call the function but not in a SQL statement.

set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
lv_date DATE;
BEGIN
lv_date:=GETDATE();
dbms_output.put_line(lv_date);
END;
```